# Codeigniter base url is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN''http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
```

http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>

```
<head>    
<title>Jotorres Login Screen | Welcome </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <div>
    <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/checkLogin.php">
    <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="78">Username</td>
    <td width="6">:</td>
    <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

base_url() is specified in Config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:81/myPro/';
```

When trying to post this form,gets an error -  "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error,I am a new to php codeigniter,thanks pls help

Comment: try to open `http://localhost:81/` in your browser.

Comment: If you did not remove index.php in ci then try this:
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/checkLogin.php">

Comment: Is this all you have in your page? if so, thats you problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've missed loading the url helper file.
Load the url helper in your config/autoload.php and it should work as expected.

The code to add url helper is as shown below:

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Answer (score 1):

Use the url helper function site_url(), this is the proper function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the library and ensure you've got the right directory structure and controllers figured out. This could be tricky for a beginning user.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter automatically adds the base_url to the action of the form when you use the form helper.

For example, you can use:

```
<?=form_open('main/login'); ?>
```

which will produce: http//example.com/main/login

And a correct URL! Pretty simple! :D More information at: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your url helper problem. you try to assingn it in url_helper.php  you also can do this same job config/autoload.php file.  you can add this code in your autoload.php

$autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `base_url()` with `site_url()`